# Page load again every button click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

My main page is something like this

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="search..." data-inset="true">
     <li data-icon="info"><a href="MsaSiparis.aspx?Msa=1">
        <img src="Img/s.jpg" width="64" height="64">
    <h2>MASA 1 </h2>
   </a></li>
    <li data-icon="info"><a href="MsaSiparis.aspx?Msa=2">
        <img src="Img/s.jpg" width="64" height="64">
    <h2>MSA 2</h2>
   </a></li>
    <li data-icon="info"><a href="MsaSiparis.aspx?Msa=3">
        <img src="Img/s.jpg" width="64" height="64">
    <h2>MSA 3</h2>
```

and I am using some jQuery script the the page directed (MsaSiparis.aspx)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnEkle").click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                 var detay = $("#cmbDetay option:selected").text();
                 var miktar = $("#cmbMiktar option:selected").text();
                 var stringSatir = "<tr><th>"+count+"</th><td>"+detay+"</td><td>"+miktar+"</td><td></td></tr>";
                 $("#table-column-toggle").append(stringSatir);
                 ++count;

                 $("#cmbMiktar option:selected").val(1);
                 $("#cmbDetay option:selected").val(1);

            });
   });
```

my button of this page like this,

```
  <button id="btnEkle" name="btnEkle" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left"> Add</button>
```

problem is the page is refresh and load again whenever I click to  Add button even if I use preventdefault.how can I solve this problem

Comment: Could you please try and add type="button" to your button? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms

Comment: use `<a>` instead of `<button>`, buttons causes refresh. and dont use `.ready()`, use _page events_ of jQM.

Comment: try `<input type="button"` instead of `<button>` either. Shouldnt do a refresh unless runat=server.

Comment: I guess the problem is related to the page direction <a href="MsaSiparis.aspx?Msa=2"> ,I tried all but not worked yet

Comment: avoid using  $(document).ready(function () { as its not recommended, use this instead  $( "#btnEkle" ).on( "click", function() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine

```
  $("#btnEkle").click(function (e) {

  });
```

Please look at http://jsfiddle.net/v3f3z/6/